# Good alternative to eregi() in PHP

Tags: php, string

I often find myself doing quick checks like this:

```
if (!eregi('.php', $fileName)) {
    $filename .= '.php';
}
```

But as [`eregi()`](http://php.net/eregi) was deprecated in PHP 5.3 the code now throws errors.

Is there another function that behaves exactly the same way as `eregi()`? I don't know anything about regexps and don't want to learn, so `preg_match()` etc won't work for me.

Comment: I hope you realize that `eregi()` IS a regular expression function. POSIX-style. `preg_match()` is a regular expression function, Perl-style.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->endsWith('.php')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L117) and all the other string functions helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[stristr](http://php.net/stristr) achieves exactly the same result as eregi (at least when you don't use regular expressions):

```
if (!stristr($fileName, '.php'))
    $filename.='.php';
```

You could also make a "fake" eregi this way:

```
if (!function_exists('eregi')) {
    function eregi($find, $str) {
        return stristr($str, $find);
    }
}
```

**Update**: Note that `stristr` doesn't accept regular expressions as `eregi` does, and for this specific case (checking the extension), you'd better go with vartec's solution.

Comment: just to be fussy: stristr is case-insensitive, if you need the case-sensitive ay use strstr

Comment: Well, eregi is case-insensitive, too :)

Comment: What if $fileName has php in the name but it's not the extension? "example.php.txt" stristr will not work for this.

Comment: You should note that `eregi` uses regular expressions and not just plain text.

Comment: @sirlancelot: You're right, but this question was about finding a replacement for eregi (which behaves in the same way as stristr when not using regular expressions), and not to check the file extension of a file :)

Comment: @Gumbo: I know that :). Click Upvote didn't want to use regular expressions though, which makes stristr more suitable for this.

Comment: @Moff, exactly. This question was about a replacement for eregi(), not  finding file extensions :)

Answer (score 19):

Of course you are aware, that this doesn't do what you expect it do do?
In regexp '.' means any character, so `eregi('.php',$fileName)` means filename with any character followed by 'php'. Thus for example "blabla2PHP.txt" will match your regexp.

Now what you want to do is this:

```
$file_ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(strtolower($file_ext) != 'php') 
   $filename .= '.php';
```

Comment: Good point, but this wasn't my question. i used the filename just as an example, what i really want is an alternative function to eregi() which returns true if a String a is found in string b, false otherwise

Answer (score 5):

Good alternative for `eregi()` is `preg_match()` with *`i`* modifier:

```
if (! preg_match('/.php/i',$fileName))
      $filename.='.php';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, I'm using this quite a lot since I updated to PHP 5 recently.

Previously:

```
if(eregi('-', $_GET['id'])
{
   return true;
}
```

Now I'm using this - it works just as good.

```
if(preg_match('/(.+)-(.+)/', $_GET['id'])) {
{
   return true;
}
```

Just replace your code with the following, and you shouldn't have any hitch of difference within your code. If you're wondering why PHP remove eregi() it's because of the performance issues it has when used a lot, so it's better to use preg_match() as it's more specific in searching so it has better performance and rendering times.

Let me know how this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you go for the "fake" eregi, you shold trigger a notice inside the fake function:
trigger_error('Some code still use eregi',E_USER_NOTICE);
This way you will easily catch the forgotten eregi calls and can replace them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should consider refactoring your code to do this instead:

```
if (substr($fileName, -4, 4) !== '.php')
    $fileName .= '.php';
```

As stated in other answers to this question, `eregi('.php')` will search for anything followed by 'php' ANYWERE in the file (not just at the end).

Answer (score 1):

I generally create and endsWith function; or other simple string manipulation functions for this kind of stuff.

```
function endsWith($string, $end){
    return substr($string, -strlen($end)) == $end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (! stristr($fileName, '.php'))
      $filename.='.php';

moff's answser had the parameters backwards.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php