# ereg_replace for PHP 5.3 +?

Tags: php, php-5.3, posix-ere

I've seen a solution for not having to rework usage of the ereg function for PHP 5.3:
[Good alternative to eregi() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737198/good-alternative-to-eregi-in-php)

It uses `if(!function_exists....`

Is there a function that can be used in this way for `ereg_replace`?

```
ereg_replace("<!--.*-->","",$str);

ereg_replace("[^a-z,A-Z]", "", $str);
```

Comment: Btw the first example is meant to display as
ereg_replace("<!--.*-->","",$str);

Answer (score 12):

Use the [PCRE function](http://docs.php.net/pcre) [`preg_replace`](http://docs.php.net/preg_replace) instead:

```
preg_replace("/<!--.*-->/", "", $str);
preg_replace("/[^a-z,A-Z]/", "", $str);
```

POSIX ERE is (nearly) a complete subset of PCRE. So you can use (nearly) any POSIX ERE regular expression with a PREG implementation. See the [Regular Expression Flavor Comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for futher details.

Comment: I totally agre... preg replaced the ereg functions a long time ago

Comment: Yes, the preg commands have been faster than the ereg commands for some time.

Answer (score 0):

This line is now raising an exception, I suspect my web host has upgrade it's PHP installation.

```
$vq = ereg_replace('[[:space:]]+', ' ', trim($vq));
```

If I just switch to preg_replace it complains about the trailing +

I was hoping for a quick fix, this was from an example I think from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/).

Comment: This looks like another question to me (and thus shouldn't be an answer), but... preg_... and ereg_... usage differs in that the preg_ functions want a delimiter wrapped around the regular expression. We often use '/' but it doesn't have to be that. (See the way the expressions in Gumbo's answer differ from the originals in the question.)