# bash: grep paragraph with regexp

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to print section (paragraph) of text between lines 
contains regexp, please help, how it could be done by grep, not awk or sed, or find regexp by grep and print with awk|sed. I use it in script, and regexp - is variable. 
param - is a pattern of extended regular expression (ERE)

```
awk  -v RS="<section>" "/$param/" "$FILE"   <!--it's now, but I need to find param by grep-->
```

example of the file:

```
<section>
 interface gigabitEthernet 7 // 192.168.248.200
  switchport access vlan 1
  switchport mode access
  port shutdown
<section>
 interface gigabitEthernet 8 // 
  switchport access vlan 2
  switchport mode trunk
<section>
```

Comment: What is `$param` in this case?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You cannot. There are many tools which can do this easily but `grep` is not one of them.

Comment: $param - is regular expression or pattern

Comment: Sory I cant read messages yesterday.  Output I expected is (if param is [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}):  interface gigabitEthernet 7 // 192.168.248.200
  switchport access vlan 1
  switchport mode access
  port shutdown

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out, `grep` is not the ideal tool for this task. However it may work if you use two of them ;-)

```
grep -Pzo "(?s)^$|<section>([^<]*${param}[^<]*)" "$FILE" | grep -v '<section>'
```

`-Pzo` activates perl regular expressions, multi-line matching and limits output to the matched part, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file).

Note that the output differs from your `awk` statement's output in whitespace and not all grep implementations support `-P`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can it be done with grep -E to find paragraph, or can I done it something else? pattern for param is extended regular expression (ERE)

Comment: @Сергей Смирнов: I don't think it can be done with `-E`. After all, `grep` is still a line-based tool. But you may find that your ERE snippet works with the PCRE engine as well. ERE is not strictly a subset of PCRE, but most ERE expressions should work (source: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1428905/4024473) on a related topic)