# php formmail doesn't work after domain changed

Tags: php, post, get, formmail

I was working on a school project and the formmail.php given from the instructor is easy and works really good.  The school ended so I signed up my own domain to save all the school works also to get more knowledge of how domain things work.

But the thing is, the formmail worked perfectly with the instructor's domain/server after I transfered everything back to the server I signed up the formmail gives me two different errors randomly when submitting the formmail.

I know and remember I had to change this in the php file in order to work.

$referers = array('et4891.com','hotmail.com'); I need to put in the domain in which I did but I still get the errors though.  I have totally 0 knowledge about php so I searched up a bit on the net and lots were talking about changing the domain which of course I did but I still get the errors.  Anyone able to give me a hand?

http://et4891.com/fpj/contact.html
The above is my own site with all the transfered files and so this contact page uses the formmail.php after filling the info and upon submitting I get either one of the errors below

http://et4891.com/fpj/formmail_error1.jpg

http://et4891.com/fpj/formmail_error2.jpg

Anyone able to give me a hand here with simple english instead I have no knowledge of php or programmings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please don't post links to pics of  the error, past them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error implies your script uses outdated code.  eregi() is a function that cant be used with PHP higher that 5.2 which your new hosting probably has (5.3 or 5.4 is most common now). Since youre not a programmer easiest solution would be to find an updated version of your formmail script.

You can always search for alternate solutions, see this [Good alternative to eregi() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737198/good-alternative-to-eregi-in-php) if you still want to try to debug the code yourself